# pandas read_csv() on_bad_lines not working with dtype

Tags: pandas

I notice `on_bad_lines="skip"` not working if `dtype` is also specified in `read_csv`. Is this expected?

```
$ cat abc.txt
ticker,qty
AAPL,100
TSLA,na

pd.read_csv("abc.txt", dtype={"qty":"int64"}, on_bad_lines="skip")
```

pandas version: 1.5.1

Comment: i think if you specify the dtype parameter, pandas will attempt to convert each column to the specified data type, and will raise an error if it encounters a value that can't be converted.

Comment: try skipping `on_bad_lines` parameter and add `errors="coerce"`

Comment: `on_bad_lines` specified and not working. That's the questions. `errors="coerce"` not available in read_csv

Comment: then maybe `na_values="na"`